# How to specify an indent of 2ch in XML-FO using FOP

Tags: css, apache-fop

I'm trying to create an indentation of two characters with a fixed-width font in an XML-FO document.  I'm translating it using FOP.

Unfortunately, when I specify a length like `"2ch"`, FOP produces this error message:

```
[ERROR] PropertyMaker - Unknown length unit 'ch'
```

The XML-FO documentation states that any CSS-known length unit is allowed, and CSS specifies that `ch` is the width of the `0` character.  So AFAIU this should work and still doesn't.

I also failed to find a concrete list of length units understood by FOP (the `ix` also didn't work).  The `em` is understood, though.  But it represents (even while using the fixed-width font monospace) a width about as wide as 1.5 characters.

Is there a way to specify to have an indent of two characters in monospace?

Is there a comprehensive list of length units supported by FOP?

Is there another way to achieve my goal of indenting by a concrete amount of characters?  I could use a hack like `1.3em` but that is probably not exact.

Comment: Do you have a source for the quote _"any CSS-known length unit is allowed"_? I could not find it in the [XSL recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl).

Comment: I Googled for `xmlfo length units` and found https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/17/xsl-fo/index.html wherein is stated: "The units below are all in centimeters, but you may use any of the CSS units, such as px (pixel), pt (point), em, in, mm, etc."  Then I looked up `css length units` and found https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp which states the `ch` unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units of measure defined in the [XSL recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#d0e5752) are:

- `cm` (centimetres)
- `mm` (millimetres)
- `in` (inches)
- `pt` (points)
- `pc` (picas)
- `px` (pixels)
- `em` (current font-size)

**FOP supports them all**, with the addition of `mpt` (millipoints), but none of them, as you noticed, refer to the width of a character for a monospaced font.

Other formatters may support additional units of measure, for example I see [AntennaHouse XSLFormatter](https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#ext-unit-conf) supports `ch`.

## Possible workarounds for FOP

If you need only a `text-indent` (i.e. just for the first line), you can use **non-breaking spaces**:

```
<fo:block>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;Lorem ipsum dolor ...</fo:block>
```

If you know in advance the block will generate just one line, you could also use **preserved regular spaces** for easier readability of the FO file:

```
<fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve" 
    white-space-collapse="false">  Lorem ipsum dolor ...</fo:block>
```

In the most general case (if you want to define a `start-indent`, `end-indent`, ...), you can compute the exact value using the font information:

1. create the font metrics

   `java -classpath build/fop.jar:fop/lib/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar:fop/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:fop/lib/commons-io-1.3.1.jar:fop/lib/xmlgraphics-commons-svn-trunk.jar org.apache.fop.fonts.apps.TTFReader -enc ansi /path/to/font.ttf metrics.xml`
2. open `metrics.xml` and look for an element similar to `<char idx="29" wdt="600"/>` (the `wdt` value can be different, but it should be the same for all `char` elements)
3. `wdt` is the width of a character in millipoints: multiply it for the `font-size` and the number of characters, and you get the length you need

**For example:** 600 x 12 x 2 = 14400mpt = 14.4pt = length of two characters with a `font-size` of 12pt

Comment: That's a bummer, but thank you for the elaborate answer.  Actually, I will stick to my current workaround of `1.2em` which seems to result exactly in what `2ch` should have been.  I cannot use too concrete stuff like font metrics because my stuff is supposed to be abstracting away fonts etc.  Also the source is going to produce several differently formatted PDFs, so nbspaces are also not possible.  If there isn't any other answer coming along (which I doubt, given your extensive research), I'll accept this answer.  Feel free to remind me after a few days in case I forget :-)