# Convert XML file to PDF using XSLT and CSS (with free software license)

Tags: css, xml, pdf, xslt, css-paged-media

I'm trying to convert XML report into PDF using XSLT and CSS. This PDF should include specific page numbering in the footer and e.g. page break after a particular table.

From what I found this can be achieved using CSS3 "at-attributes" for "paged media" (e.g. `@page`). However, if I understand correctly, I might have a problem finding a tool that interprets these attributes to create PDF (not to mention that it needs to converts from XML first).

I found that I could use `paged.js` script to have it working in a browser, but it works only if I run local server (e.g. `live-server`) because of some local file restriction in all web browsers. I can (kind of) overcome this using command line switches like `--allow-file-access-from-files` but it prints the document before rendering is complete (it looks like the browser do not wait for the `paged.js` script to finish). I tried different switches: `chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --allow-file-access-from-files --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=100000 --print-to-pdf="<destination>" "<source>"`. Perhaps some switches for node engine could help?

**My question is how can I programmatically convert the XML file to PDF, using XSLT to extract data of interest from XML, and CSS to format PDF as the proper paged document, using software with a free commercial license? Do I need `paged.js` to accomplish it?**

About my files:
In my XML file, I reference local XSL files that extract particular data from XML; they remove duplicates and sort them by date. This XSL file reference local CSS file to provide nice formatting and also "paged" attributes. XSL reference also `paged.js` script and associated CSS, as in the [script documentation](https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/02-getting-started-with-paged-js/).

I tried, between the other, `weasyprint`, `htmldoc`, `html5-to-pdf` and `wkhtmltopdf` without success.

I'm open for any suggestion.

---

**EDIT:** I was experimenting with XSL-FO (as suggested in the comment) and I have to admit that it works pretty well. It seems to me that page control is even more readable than in CSS. The only problem I see now is that it requires additional installations (Apache FOP and Java Runtime Environment). In my scenario it would be better to have FOP in .NET.

Anyway, I decided to describe in more detail my CSS-based solution with Chrome as a renderer because it does not requires additional installers (or at least that what I think). I already spend some time with it and it seems that it's almost working. Perhaps someone will spot where the problem is and then it would become a pretty nice solution for paged media with CSS.

Complete `transform.xsl` file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Summary</title>
            <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <link href="css/interface.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <script src="js/paged.polyfill.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Summary</h1>
            <table class="summary">
                <tr><td>Total Quantity:</td><td><xsl:value-of select="count(Results/Result)"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Passed:</td><td><xsl:value-of select="count(Results/Result[Status='Pass'])"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Failed:</td><td><xsl:value-of select="count(Results/Result[Status='Fail'])"/></td></tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Results">
        <table class="results">
            <tr>
                <th>Serial Number</th>
                <th>Test Result</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Result">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="./Status"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="./SerialNumber"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="./Status"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="./Date"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="./Time"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my `style.css` I have `@page` rules as below. There is more in my original file but it's not important here.

```css
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 2cm 1cm;

    @top-left {
        content: "Summary Continued...";
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    @bottom-center{
        content: "Page " counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

@page :first {
    @top-left {
        content: "";
    }
}
```

And data is stored in `Reports.xml` (see below). In this xml file you can put as many `Result` fields as you want. I have 200 results in my file but I truncated it here to make it clearer.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl/transform.xsl"?>

<Results>
    <Result ID="0">
        <SerialNumber>8652280431</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>05-Mar-21</Date>
        <Time>08:56:23</Time>
    </Result>
    <Result ID="1">
        <SerialNumber>11124002643</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>05-Mar-21</Date>
        <Time>08:56:23</Time>
    </Result>
.
.
.
    <Result ID="200">
        <SerialNumber>6616001379</SerialNumber>
        <Status>Fail</Status>
        <Date>05-Mar-21</Date>
        <Time>08:56:23</Time>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

I also have in my files `interface.css` and `paged.polyfill.js` as described in the [documentation](https://www.pagedjs.org/documentation/02-getting-started-with-paged-js/) (see `transform.xsl`).

When I open my `Results.xml` in Chrome with the command `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files <file path>` it works as excepted (see image below).

[image]

When I try to print my `Results.xml` in Chrome with command `chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --allow-file-access-from-files --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=100000 --print-to-pdf=<destination> <source>` it generates unexpected results. Only couple pages are generated and total page count (`counter(pages)`) returns 0 in the footer (see image below).

[image]

So maybe someone will figure how to make it work.

Perhaps `--js-flags` will do the trick? Or maybe I should add/change something in `paged.polyfill.js`?

Comment: Why CSS? Does the usual way XML -> XSL-FO -> PDF using any XSLT processor for the first transformation and e.g. Apache FOP for the second transformation not work?

Comment: I'm not entirely against using XSL-FO, but I've already invested some time in CSS variant, which is more readable IMHO. Also, according to different sources XSL-FO is dying and should be replaced by CSS3 if possible. Currently XSL-FO would be a last resort for me, which I will try to avoid because I would need to probably invest a lot more time in this solution. I have to admit that in the beginning I thought that what I try to accomplish is something common and easy. But now, it seems to me it's something unusual...

Comment: Mark Twain had a similar problem: https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/562400/reports-mark-twains-quote-about-mark-twains-death-are-greatly-exaggerated. The guy who wrote that XSL-FO is dead updated his post - https://readwritecode.net/ebooks/2019/04/27/xsl-fo-is-dead-css-paged-media-is-prime-suspect.html - and now says the XSL-FO is alive and kicking: https://readwritecode.net/ebooks/2019/04/28/xsl-fo-is-alive-and-kicking.html. Even so, you should use the tool that works best for you.

Comment: FWIW, it's an "'@page' rule" (see https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#at-ruledef-page). You might be interested in the 'Introduction to CSS for Page Media' book at https://www.antennahouse.com/css, where you can download both the PDF and the source.

Comment: The latest version of Apache FOP 2.6 is from this year. Probably a lot of your css can be used in XslFo. You benefit from years of improvement of the codebase like adding accessibility to your pdf’s.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed What do you mean by "css can be used in XslFo"? Do you mean that the way I formatted my document with CSS can be recreated using XSL-FO, or that I can use exactly what I have in CSS? I think I need to recreate everything because from what I see, even font size is a problem (pt vs px).

I know I can use XSL-FO, but I already see that it will take couple days to recreate everything.

Comment: I mean that a lot of css properties can be used in XslFo. px can be used.  See answer about units https://stackoverflow.com/a/46265259/3710053